# C Programming - fprintf and printf in while cicle doesn't work

Tags: c, file, while-loop, linked-list, printf

I'm getting a strange problem with a while cicle inside of a function.

I have to look for the extreme vertices of a .ply model. All the data is stored in a linked list. When I'm done creating the list, I call the findExtremeVertex function, that modifies 6 global variables (leftVertex, rightVertex, downwardVertex, upwardVertex, backVertex and frontVertex).

To see if the values are right (the models I use are a bit too big to control every single line to find the maximum of every vertex) I decided to print every change in the max-min values but, when I try to print them in a file, the file is empty. Why is that? Also, when I saw that the file was empty, I tried to print something directly in the console but that didn't work either.

Here's the code of the funcion:

```
void findExtremeVertex(Vertex *vertex){
    FILE *modelInfoFile;
    int i = 0;

    ///Giving data to direction-vertices pointers
    leftVertex = malloc(sizeof(Vertex));
    rightVertex = malloc(sizeof(Vertex));
    upwardVertex = malloc(sizeof(Vertex));
    downwardVertex = malloc(sizeof(Vertex));
    frontVertex = malloc(sizeof(Vertex));
    backVertex = malloc(sizeof(Vertex));

    ///Giving the direction-vertices the values of the parameter
    leftVertex = vertex;
    rightVertex = vertex;
    upwardVertex = vertex;
    downwardVertex = vertex;
    frontVertex = vertex;
    backVertex = vertex;

    ///Opening file
    modelInfoFile = fopen(us2, "w");
    if(modelInfoFile == NULL){
        printf("Error in file opening. Exiting.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ///Scrolling the list
    while(vertex->prev != NULL){
        vertex = vertex->prev;

        ///If the given element of the list is more to the right than the global variable,
        ///I assign the values of the element to the global variable
        if(vertex->vertexCoordinates.x > rightVertex->vertexCoordinates.x){
            rightVertex = vertex;
        }

        /**
            I'm omitting the other if constructs because are basically
            the same, but the syntax is correct
        **/

        ///Printing in file the cycle information
        fprintf(modelInfoFile, "********** CYCLE %d **********\n\n", i);
        fprintf(modelInfoFile, "Vertex sx\n");
        fprintf(modelInfoFile, "%1.4f %1.4f %1.4f %1.4f %1.4f %1.4f\n\n", leftVertex->vertexCoordinates.x,
                                                                      leftVertex->vertexCoordinates.y,
                                                                      leftVertex->vertexCoordinates.z,
                                                                      leftVertex->vertexNormals.x,
                                                                      leftVertex->vertexNormals.y,
                                                                      leftVertex->vertexNormals.z);

        /**
            Again, I'm omitting some repetitions but the syntax is correct
        **/
        }
    }
```

I call this function in another function, but there's no segmentation fault signal, the compiler doesn't tell me anything, the program doesn't crash. I have no clue of the error, except from the fact that the file where I print the infos about the cycles is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have several problems!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many problems in your code.

1. You `malloc()` 6 variables and never use any of them, and you don't check if `malloc()` succeeded.
2. **You never call `fclose()` or `fflush()` so maybe you are seeing the file before the data is flushed to the disk.**
3. You reassign all the `*Vertex` (except for `rightVertex`) variables after they are `malloc()`ed to the same pointer `vertex` which means

   1. You are causing a memory leak.
   2. You are using 6 variables for a single pointer.
4. All the `*Vertex` variables are not declared inside the function which means that they are in the global scope, that is very likely a bad design choice. Given the code you posted it's not possible to tell whether or not global variables are the right choice, but 99% of the time they are a bad choice and there is a much more elegant and safe way to do things.

The **bold** point above is likely the reason why your program is behaving as it is.

Comment: 1 - Yeah I don't check if malloc succeed, but I thought that, if malloc doesn't allocate space, there would be a segmentation fault. Anyway, I tried to set some exits and the problem is the same; 2- I tried that to, in the function this function is called and within the function itself, but it didn't solve the problem; 3a - Yes, I am causing a memory leak, but it's not a problem, luckly I don't have to make the program rum on weak machines so I suppose it's ok. However, even if I deallocate all the variables at the end of the while loop, I still don't get the printed data on the file;

Comment: 3b - Yes I am, is it a wrong thing to do? I have to keep track of these infos, and I don't know how to do it if all the variables reunite into 1 only; 4 - I know, the global variables choiche is stupid in this case, but the main function of this program is recursive and I have to keep track of too many things, so I decided to use extensively the glob scope (thanks for responding so extensively man!)

Comment: @alemootasa 1. That is a terrible reason to omit the check, you could say that your computer has infinite RAM and it would sound better.  2. You MUST NOT rely on segmentation faults! They occur almost always when the program invokes undefined behavior, and since it's undefined it's NOT RELIABLE!

Comment: @alemootasa The `main()` function cannot be recursive, you mean the function that you call from `main()`? And it doesn't matter, create a struct to hold whatever data you need and pass it accross the functions, that would have 2 benefits: 1. You wouldn't need global variables that can cause stupid mistakes. 2. You would have a more "realistic" description of your problem/solution written as a computer program.

Comment: Yeah maybe I rely too much on errors, actually the whole program works if there's an error check in mani() function. And yes, it's not the main() function the one that's recursive, I meant that the most important function in the program is recursive. In that case I'll try to solve these major problems first and then return on this dumb fprintf function. I'm sure I'll resolve them if I follow your advices, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
leftVertex = vertex;
rightVertex = vertex;
upwardVertex = vertex;
downwardVertex = vertex;
frontVertex = vertex;
backVertex = vertex;
```

sets the pointer value but not the actual value. You malloc space, get a pointer to that space, and then throw that pointer away setting it to the pointer of virtex.

Do you mean to use

```
*leftVertex = *vertex;
*rightVertex = *vertex;
*upwardVertex = *vertex;
*downwardVertex = *vertex;
*frontVertex = *vertex;
*backVertex = *vertex;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
///Scrolling the list
while(vertex->prev != NULL){
    vertex = vertex->prev;
```

And what happens if `vertex` is NULL after this?

You're checking if it's NULL, then changing it's value such that it can become NULL.

Comment: The problem you mentioned shouldn't present, because the condition to continue the loop is that the prev argument of the structure must be != NULL. So, if prev is NULL, the loop stops. Am I wrong? At least, that's the way i thought about it!

Comment: @alemootasa It would only happen if the very first `vertex` is `NULL` which you didn't check anywhere. This would cause undefined behavior and it might be the problem, check if `vertex` is `NULL` before dereferencing it and see maybe that fixes the problem.

Comment: It didn't fixed the problem, too bad. Anyway, the first vertex could not be NULL because I'm always passing a legit parameter to this function, there's a check in another function. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
  ///Opening file
if(modelInfoFile == NULL){
    printf("Error in file opening. Exiting.");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

I don't see you opening file.

```
if((modelInfoFile=fopen(filename,"w")) == NULL){
```

Should work.

### EDIT

In you while loop you change -

```
   vertex = vertex->prev;
```

But in `fprintf` you store in file in value of `leftVertex->vertexCoordinates.x`
So how do you expect to print inside file correctly.

Comment: Yeah sorry, in the actual program I do. I edited the code

Comment: @alemootasa What is `us2` ?

Comment: @iharob I did, the only missing thing was the missin fopen

Comment: @ameyCU us2 is a string, I use as a filepath. It's global and already initialized

Comment: That means that it's not exact. I mean Ctrl+V -> Ctrl+C